# Reorder symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

EDITED: Suppose I have a symmetric matrix such as the one below.

```
dat<-c(NA,2,3,4,5,2,NA,8,9,10,3,8,NA,14,15,4,9,14,NA,20,5,10,15,20,NA)
x<-matrix(dat,nrow = 5,dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c("A","B","C","D","E")))
x
```

I'm trying to see if there is any way we can use R to reorder the matrix in such a way that the highest values are closer to the diagonal, with the maximum value of each column of the lower triangle as the first item in the diagonal, and also it maintains its symmetry. This is a problem in card sorting.

Here is the desired output:

```
result<-c(NA,20,15,10,5,20,NA,14,9,4,15,14,NA,8,3,10,9,8,NA,2,5,4,3,2,NA)
y<-matrix(result,nrow = 5,dimnames = list(c("E","D","C","B","A"),c("E","D","C","B","A")))
y
```

Comment: Instead of a (relatively) big 14x14 matrix, could you edit your question to have a smaller  example? It will be easier to import, understand your problem, and debug solutions. Maybe give a 4x4 or 5x5 example, in valid R syntax, and show both the input and the desired output?

Comment: I think a worked example would clear it up, but I want to make sure I understand. By "reorder", do you want to reorder values *within* columns in the lower triangle? Or within rows? Or either/both?

Comment: I've edited my question to a 5x5 example, and also included what the result should look like.

Comment: Does this need to be attempt by swapping intact rows?

Comment: Yes, when the columns are sorted, then the rows must also change so that it remains a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement when examining a matrix containing similarities between documents.

```
k <- apply(x, 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
order <- sort(k, decreasing=TRUE, index.return=TRUE)$ix
x[order, order]
```

I use `max` on each row to find the maximum value per row. `na.rm` ensures that the diagonal is not considered. `sort` then provides the desired order as a vector. Reorganising the matrix according to that order is as simple as `x[order, order]`.

Comment: Thanks James. This is very helpful.